# route infrastructure for webapps - express

Tags: ajax, http, web-applications, express

I'm very new to this topic, so please excuse me if this is an obvious question.

From my understanding traditional webpages (VS kind of modern webapps) provide specific routes like `www.example.com/path1` to serve specific pages. Lets say on this route there might be some parallel DB queries to `resource1`, `resource2`.

Now in a more modern webapp there might exist multiple ajax calls. If every call requests `www.example.com/path1` that would lead to unnecessary DB traffic, wouldn't it?

The question is how to set up the routes for this kind of application?

Something like: `www.example.com/resource1`, `www.example.com/resource2`, ... and every ajax call requests his own specific route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typcial pattern for express apps is to serve HTML templates as static resources, powered by a JSON REST API for your AJAX calls. For example, you could have a structure like this:

`GET /api/articles` to list all articles

`POST /api/articles` to create a new article

`GET /api/articles/{article_id}` to fetch a specific article

..and so on. These APIs will return JSON data that gets rendered by javascript and HTML templates running client side in the user's browser.

It's also typical that a browser request made to `http://example.com/articles` will only return a basic index.html template, and your client side javascript will take care of making the appropriate ajax call to `/api/articles` to get the actual data.

You might aslo remove the `/api` prefix for your JSON API routes, and instead use URL fragments for your client side routes, which would look like this: `http://example.com/#!/articles/123`. This is the pattern that [mean.js](http://meanjs.org/) follows for example.

Note that this is not the only way to do things, depending on your needs it may not be the best way. These are simply common patterns used for building apps in express.js.